# Is it possible to send a letter from LAX airport while in transit there?

Tags: transit, mail, lax

A friend is flying to Europe, transiting through LAX. She has some things she'd like to send to friends in the US so is wondering whether it is possible to send letters or parcels from LAX in transit? Is there a parcel/post service available in the international terminal?

A map of the terminal doesn't show anything obvious, and I think it's unlikely possibly due to needing to clear customs with the packages, but that's just an uneducated guess.

Comment: Everybody who transits through the US has to clear immigration and customs with all their luggage, and then she'll be landside with everything, So customs wouldn't be a concern - it's just a matter of finding whether there is a conveniently located post office.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well that's a start - I wasn't aware of that.  I'll find out how long their wait is

Comment: [This Trip Advisor thread](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g32655-i61-k9356521-Where_is_the_USPS_post_office_in_LAX-Los_Angeles_California.html) suggests that there isn't one, but that Customer Service might mail a letter if you ask nicely.  If it's really important she can take a taxi to a post office - there is one not far from the airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the LAX website, [postal services are not available in any of the terminals at LAX](http://www.lawa.org/welcome_LAX.aspx?id=1588). It has been a while since I have seen a post office in any airport terminal in the U.S., which I assume owes to a combination of the declining use of postal mail in general and the heightened sensitivity to possible terror attacks through packaged bombs or anthrax.

You might be able to leave postcards or envelopes with the staff at an airport lounge, although the willingness of staff to take mail seems to be variable. I was not able to find anything authoritative as to purchasing US postage at the airport. If there is a news kiosk or bookstore in your terminal, you can ask.

In any case, the nearest U.S. Post Office is a distance away at 9029 Airport Boulevard, across the street from the Hertz on one side and Avis from another. The Avis shuttle would be slightly more convenient, for what it's worth, but it would still be very time-consuming to do on a layover.

For shipping packages, there are also appears to be a FedEx location in the [Los Angeles Airport Marriott](http://www.fedex.com/us/office/Hotels-Conventions/marriott-LAX.html) (5855 W Century Blvd), and another in the [Westin Los Angeles Airport Hotel](http://www.westinlosangelesairport.com/fedex-office) (11221 S Hindry Ave), both with limited hours. The nearest UPS STore is in a strip mall at [8939 S Sepulveda Blvd](https://westchester-ca-4417.theupsstorelocal.com/). A taxi will be most convenient for these locations.

Comment: At Denver (DEN), there is a full-service post office in the landside terminal, and I am pretty sure I remember seeing public mailboxes airside where you could mail a letter (but probably not a parcel).  So they do exist in some places, just apparently not at LAX.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that one. That's what I get for not flying United since shortly after the merger. But on the plus side, I haven't flown United since shortly after the merger.